# Creating Custom Time Picker Widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to create a widget that is used to pick a time. QTimeEdit widget doesn't seem intuitive or a good design. So I decided to create a time picker similar to the time picker in smartphones.

[image]

I managed to create the clock and click that makes the pointer (something similar to the pointer in the image) move to the currently clicked position (note: it's not perfect, it still looks bad). I would like to have help with making the inner clock

Here is my code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import math, sys


class ClockWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):   # I want to be able to reuse this class for other programs also, so please don't hard code values of the list, start and end

    def __init__(self, start, end, lst=[], *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClockWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.lst = lst

        if not self.lst:
            self.lst = [*range(start, end)]

        self.index_start = 0  # tune this to move the letters in the circle
        self.pointer_angles_multiplier = 9  # just setting the default values

        self.current = None
        self.rects = []

    @property
    def index_start(self):
        return self._index_start

    @index_start.setter
    def index_start(self, index):
        self._index_start = index

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        self.rects = []

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.red)
        pen.setWidth(2)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        x, y = self.rect().x(), self.rect().y()
        width, height = self.rect().width(), self.rect().height()

        painter.drawEllipse(x, y, x + width, x + height)

        s, t, equal_angles, radius = self.angle_calc()
        radius -= 30

        pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.green)
        pen.setWidth(2)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        """ pointer angle helps in determining to which position the pointer should be drawn"""
        self.pointer_x, self.pointer_y = s + ((radius-30) * math.cos(self.pointer_angles_multiplier * equal_angles)), t \
                + ((radius-30)  * math.sin(self.pointer_angles_multiplier * equal_angles))

        """ The pendulum like pointer """
        painter.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(s, t), QtCore.QPointF(self.pointer_x, self.pointer_y))

        painter.drawEllipse(QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(self.pointer_x - 20, self.pointer_y - 40),
                                          QtCore.QPointF(self.pointer_x + 30, self.pointer_y + 10)))

        pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        pen.setWidth(3)

        font = self.font()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        painter.setFont(font)

        painter.setPen(pen)

        """ Drawing the number around the circle formula y = t + radius * cos(a)
            y = s + radius * sin(a) where angle is in radians (s, t) are the mid point of the circle """
        for index, char in enumerate(self.lst, start=self.index_start):
            angle = equal_angles * index

            y = t + radius * math.sin(angle)
            x = s + radius * math.cos(angle)

            # print(f"Add: {add_x}, index: {index}; char: {char}")
            rect = QtCore.QRectF(x - 30, y - 40, x + 60, y)  # clickable point

            self.rects.append([index, char, rect])  # appends index, letter, rect

            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.blue)
            painter.drawRect(rect)  # helps in visualizing the points where the click can received

            print(f"Rect: {rect}; char: {char}")
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.red)

            points = QtCore.QPointF(x, y)
            painter.drawText(points, str(char))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):

        for x in self.rects:

            index, char, rect = x

            if event.button() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton and rect.contains(event.pos()):

                self.pointer_angles_multiplier = index
                self.current = char
                self.update()
                break

    def angle_calc(self):
        """
         This will simply return (midpoints of circle, divides a circle into the len(list) and return the
         angle in radians, radius)
         """
        return ((self.rect().width() - self.rect().x()) / 2, (self.rect().height() - self.rect().y()) / 2,
                (360 / len(self.lst)) * (math.pi / 180), (self.rect().width() / 2))

    def resizeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QResizeEvent):
        """This is supposed to maintain a Square aspect ratio on widget resizing but doesn't work
        correctly as you will see when executing"""

        if event.size().width() > event.size().height():
            self.resize(event.size().height(), event.size().width())

        else:
            self.resize(event.size().width(), event.size().width())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    message = ClockWidget(1, 13)
    message.index_start = 10
    message.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The Output:

[image]

The blue rectangles represent the clickable region. I would be glad if you could also, make the pointer move to the closest number when clicked inside the clock (Not just move the pointer when the clicked inside the blue region)

There is one more problem in my code, that is the numbers are not evenly spaced from the outer circle. (like the number 12 is closer to the outer circle than the number 6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I will not explain the cause of the error but the code I provide I think should give a clear explanation of the errors.

The logic is to calculate the position of the centers of each small circle, and use the exinscribed rectangle to take it as a base to draw the text and check if the point where you click is close to the texts.

```py
from functools import cached_property
import math
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ClockWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    L = 12
    r = 40.0
    DELTA_ANGLE = 2 * math.pi / L
    current_index = 9

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        R = min(self.rect().width(), self.rect().height()) / 2
        margin = 4

        Rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 2 * R - margin, 2 * R - margin)
        Rect.moveCenter(self.rect().center())

        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("gray"))
        painter.drawEllipse(Rect)

        rect = QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, self.r, self.r)

        if 0 <= self.current_index < 12:
            c = self.center_by_index(self.current_index)
            rect.moveCenter(c)
            pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("red"))
            pen.setWidth(5)
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.drawLine(c, self.rect().center())

            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("red"))
            painter.drawEllipse(rect)

        for i in range(self.L):
            j = (i + 2) % self.L + 1
            c = self.center_by_index(i)
            rect.moveCenter(c)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QColor("white"))
            painter.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, str(j))

    def center_by_index(self, index):
        R = min(self.rect().width(), self.rect().height()) / 2
        angle = self.DELTA_ANGLE * index
        center = self.rect().center()

        return center + (R - self.r) * QtCore.QPointF(math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle))

    def index_by_click(self, pos):
        for i in range(self.L):
            c = self.center_by_index(i)
            delta = QtGui.QVector2D(pos).distanceToPoint(QtGui.QVector2D(c))
            if delta < self.r:
                return i
        return -1

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        i = self.index_by_click(event.pos())
        if i >= 0:
            self.current_index = i
            self.update()

    @property
    def hour(self):
        return (self.current_index + 2) % self.L + 1

    def minumumSizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(100, 100)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = ClockWidget()
    view.resize(400, 400)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]